Doesn't contain any ground-truth entity defined in the Schema
while training a Google Document Classifyer, the training failed with the below errors.
On inspection of the error, I noticed that all failed documents belong to classification lables which have been disabled due to insuficcent data at the time.
I am wondering why Google is tryingin to import documents which are match agained a disabled labled. Shouldnt they be skipped by default? Any advice how to solve and to go from here would be appriciated. Delete the document from the bucket (side issue, re-sync storage does not work, delete items in the bucket remain even after sync as the count of total document does not decrease)? Delete the lable for now?
          "code": 3,
      "message": "Invalid document.",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
          "reason": "INVALID_DOCUMENT",
          "domain": "documentai.googleapis.com",
          "metadata": {
            "document": "gs://PATH TO DOCUMENT",
            "reason": "The document:  doesn't contain any ground-truth entity defined in the Schema."

Thank you all in advance.
